# Pointing custom domain in Route53 to Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a Cloudfront distribution that points to my app that is hosted on Heroku. This seems to work fine as when I go to the Cloudfront URL `xxxxxx.cloudfront.net`, it shows my website.

But when I add a domain in Route53 as an A record with an Alias pointing to my Cloudfront distribution, I get 403 forbidden.

I'm not sure what config details I can show but happy to show more on request.

My setup is as follows:

Domain hosted on Route53 with an A record Alias pointing to Cloudfront

Cloudfront distribution with SSL cert pointing to Heroku URL `example.herokuapp.com`

Heroku app is a React website.

Cloudfront and Heroku seems to work fine, but what could be wrong with my Route53 setup?

Comment: Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=12s

Comment: You haven't mentioned [doing the necessary configuration to tell CloudFront about this custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html).  Check that?